# I have SSL certificate on sql server but how to connect sql server 2008 2008 r2 enterprise using php

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

If I disable force encryption from ms-sql server, ms-sql connection is establish successfully.
But when I enable force encryption from ms-sql server I get following error:

> Warning: mssql_connect() [function.mssql-connect]: Unable to connect to server:

In php.ini I am using this setting for secure connection - `mssql.secure_connection on`

Can anybody help me to connect ms-sql server 2008 from php?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for a way to ignore verifying the SSL certificate.